Did Donald Trump tell Americans to inject bleach to prevent or cure COVID-19?
In a March 20 speech, Joe Biden claimed:

He [Trump] told Americans — remember he was telling "inject bleach"?

He repeated this claim (sometimes claiming drinking, mostly claiming injecting) many times: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24.
Did Donald Trump tell Americans to inject bleach?

Disappointing to see this question closed as duplicate of a closed question.  Also, this claim is much more specific, "inject bleach".  The other question was closed as "opinion based" while this question is not opinion based.

Replacing one word with something that's almost a synonym but otherwise asking the same question about the same underlying incident is a duplicate. If you think the old question shouldn't be closed I'd open that one, it has better answers anyway

@CJR The title of the other question is similar, but the body of the other question is much more vague.

@CJR Bleach and disinfectant aren't synonyms. It is stupid to equate them. "Disinfectant" is a very broad category that includes alcohols, chlorines, iodine compounds, ultraviolet light, and much more.

Trump talks about injecting disinfectant after a discussion about how cleaning agents such as bleach could kill Covid
President Trump Suggests ‘Injecting’ Disinfectant as Coronavirus Cure | NBC New York
Coronavirus: Outcry after Trump suggests injecting disinfectant as treatment

"And then I see the disinfectant where it knocks it out in a minute.
One minute. And is there a way we can do something like that, by
injection inside or almost a cleaning?
"So it'd be interesting to
check that."

Fact Check: Did Trump once tell Americans to inject bleach to fight COVID-19?

Specht: Bryan said that his team had done some experiments that found
that sun exposure and disinfectants, cleaning agents like bleach,
could kill COVID-19 on surfaces and in the air. He eventually steps
aside and says, you know, this concludes my research, we have some
good stuff to go on.
Then, Trump takes the mic and sort of riffs. He's looking back and
forth at reporters, and then Bryan, who's sitting off to the side. And
Trump says, speaking to reporters, you know, a question that a lot of
you are probably thinking is, what if we hit the body — this is his
words — with a tremendous ultraviolet or very powerful light — and I'm
sort of paraphrasing here for the sake of clarity.
And then he turns to Bryan and says, I think you said that hasn't been
checked, but you're going to test it, which you can do either through
the skin or some other way, and I think you said you're gonna test
that. Sounds interesting, right?
And he goes on, he says, and I see the disinfectant where it knocks it
out in one minute. Is there a way we could do something like that by
injection inside or almost a cleaning because you can see, it gets in
the lungs — he's referring to the virus now — it does a tremendous
number on the lungs, and I think it'd be interesting to check that. So
he’s sort of rambling here and these comments created confusion.
Almost immediately after that, a reporter, who was sitting in this
press briefing room asked him, did you just say you’re testing
injections? And Bryan came back to the microphone and said no, no,
that's not what we tested in our lab. And Trump also clarified, he
said well, that's not what I meant, it wouldn't be through injections,
it would be cleaning and sterilization of an area.
And so it appeared that they shut it down and clarified what they
meant just moments later, but the press had already taken off with
these comments that Trump made.
[...]
Terry: So how did you rate this claim by President Biden?
Specht: Mostly false. Trump did mention bringing UV rays and disinfectants into the body, but let's remember what Biden said. He said his predecessor, quote, "told Americans all they had to do was inject bleach in themselves, just take a shot of UV light." That is not what Trump said. It was by no means a demand, an instruction, a recommendation. Trump was speaking off the cuff. And then, scientists say, in an ill-advised way. He was not telling anyone to do anything. He was floating ideas for potential treatments to be tested. That's why we rated Biden's claim that Trump told people to inject bleach mostly false.


The claim is false. Trump did not tell Amercians to inject bleach.
Snopes: Trump didn't tell people to 'inject bleach' for COVID-19.

During an April 2020 media briefing, Trump did ask members of the government's coronavirus task force to look into whether disinfectants could be injected inside people to treat COVID-19. But when a reporter asked in a follow-up question whether cleaning products like bleach and isopropyl alcohol would be injected into a person, the then-president said those products would be used for sterilizing an area, not for injections. However, at no point did Trump explicitly tell people they could or should inject bleach into their bodies.

PolitiFact: No, Trump didn’t tell Americans infected with the coronavirus to drink bleach

Joe Biden said President Donald Trump told Americans that drinking bleach could help combat the coronavirus, but that’s not correct. Trump did not explicitly recommend ingesting a disinfectant like bleach. But he did express interest in exploring whether disinfectants could be applied to the site of a coronavirus infection inside the body, such as the lungs.

PolitiFact: Biden exaggerates Trump’s pandemic comments about disinfectants, UV light

Biden said Trump "told Americans all they had to do was inject bleach in themselves. Just take a shot of UV light." Biden was referring to comments Trump made in 2020 about potential treatments for COVID-19, which were roundly criticized. However, Trump didn’t explicitly tell Americans to inject or "take a shot" of anything.

The New York Times: Fact-Checking Biden’s ABC Interview

This is exaggerated. Mr. Trump’s comments, in April 2020, about the efficacy of disinfectants and light as treatments for the coronavirus sparked uproar and confusion. He did not instruct people to inject bleach, but suggested that doing so with a disinfectant was an “interesting” concept to test out.

The Washington Post: Fact-checking the first Biden-Trump 2024 presidential debate

Trump did not say people should inject bleach in their arm. Instead, at a pandemic briefing in 2020 he spoke confusingly of an “injection inside” of lungs with a disinfectant.

WCVB: Fact-checking the presidential debate between Biden, Trump

This is not what Trump said. Back in 2020, during a news conference, Trump suggested that scientists test the use of "very powerful light" and "disinfectant" in the body to kill the virus. He mentioned an injection at one point, but he never said to use bleach, and he did not tell people to inject themselves.

Trump's actual statement was the following:

So, supposedly we hit the body with a tremendous, whether it’s ultraviolet or just very powerful light, and I think you said that hasn’t been checked, but you’re going to test it. And then I said supposing you brought the light inside the body, which you can do either through the skin or in some other way. And I think you said you’re going to test that too. Sounds interesting, right? And then I see the disinfectant, where it knocks it out in one minute. And is there a way we can do something like that by injection inside or almost a cleaning because you see it gets in the lungs and it does a tremendous number on the lungs, so it’d be interesting to check that so that you’re going to have to use medical doctors with, but it sounds interesting to me. So, we’ll see, but the whole concept of the light, the way it kills it in one minute. That’s pretty powerful.

The use of disinfectants (a category much broader than "bleach"), such as alcohol, inside the body to treat COVID-19 has been the subject of research:

Possibility of Disinfection of SARS-CoV-2 (COVID-19) in Human Respiratory Tract by Controlled Ethanol Vapor Inhalation
New Treatment for COVID-19 Using Ethanol Vapor Inhalation
Disinfection of SARS-COV-2 (COVID-19) in human respiratory tract by controlled ethanol vapor inhalation combined with aspirin
Efficacy and Safety of Inhalation of Nebulized Ethanol in COVID-19 Treatment: A Randomized Clinical Trial
Efficacy and Safety of Inhaled Ethanol in Early-Stage SARS-CoV-2 Infection in Older Adults: A Phase II Randomized Clinical Trial

